# Is there a correspondence between normal subgroups and representations of a (finite) group?

Tags: representation-theory

I read this short introductory paper about representation theory: http://quantum.phys.cmu.edu/qm2/qmc151.pdf

The dihedral group $D_3$ is described as having three representations:

- One faithful representation of the group (the fundamental one?)
- The trivial one.
- The third one I would describe like this: $D_3 \to Z_2 = \left\{ \mathbb{1}, -\mathbb{1} \right\} \to V$. If $D_3$ is interpreted as the symmetry group of the unilateral triangle, then this representation maps all rotations to the identity, and all reflections to one single reflection. Thus, this has the structure of the cyclic group of order two, $Z_2$.

These three representations correspond exactly to the normal subgroups of $D_3$, if you count the trivial subgroups as normal subgroups:

- $D_3$ corresponds to the faithful representation.
- $\{1\}$ corresponds to the trivial one.
- The third one corresponds to $Z_3$, which is the only normal subgroup of $D_3$.

Is this a regular pattern? Is there a theorem that says that there's a bijection between the normal subgroups of a group and its irreps?

If there is a regular pattern, how does it expand to infinite cases like $SO(3)$?

Comment: It isn't $1-1$, in general. But if $H$ is a normal subgroup of $G$ then a representation of $G/H$ is also a representation of $G$. The Dihedral group  $D_3$ is really small  - the smallest non-abelian group, in fact - a fairly poor example to try to build generalizations.

Comment: Thanks, I suppose that holds too in the infinite case?

Comment: don't know much about representations of infinite groups.

Comment: Isn't $SO(3)$ simple? That is, it has no non-trivial normal subgroups. Anyway, I'm seconding what Thomas said. You can "inflate" irreducible representations of a quotient group to irreducibles of the mother group. So in your example I would rather say that both the 1-dimensional irreps of $D_3$ are gotten by inflating the irreps of the quotient group $\cong C_2$.

Answer (score 3):

If we work over $\mathbb C$ then the number of irreducible representations of a group is equal to the number of conjugacy classes of elements in that group.  For an abelian group this is simply the number of elements in the group.  Also in an abelian group every subgroup is normal, so the number of normal subgroups is equal to the number of subgroups.

I think it's quite uncommon for the number of subgroups of an abelian group to equal the number of elements.  Any cyclic group of order larger than $2$ is a counterexample.  So the correspondence you're suggesting does not hold.

In general there is a correspondence which involves normal subgroups though.  The representations of $G$ are in correspondence with pairs $(N, \rho)$ where $N$ is a normal subgroup of $G$ and $\rho$ is a faithful representation of $G/N$.  You just happened to pick a group $G$ such that for every normal subgroup $N$ there is a unique faithful representation of the group $G/N$.